# Rails - get objects where parent id is not in any of the child associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join

I have these two models:

```
Collabs
- id
- title
# has_many :collaborations

Collaborations
- collab_id
- user_id
- status
# belongs_to :collab
# belong_to :user
```

In a query, I wan't to to fetch all the collabs, where a certain user_id is NOT present in the child (collaborations) association. A collab can have zero to many collaborations, and the collaborations will have different user_id's.

I've tried (using scopes):

```
collabs = Collab.available_for_user(2)

scope :available_for_user, -> (user_id) { joins(:collaborations).where.not(collaborations: {user_id: user_id}) }
```

I also tried:

```
scope :available_for_user, -> (user_id) { left_outer_joins(:collaborations).where.not(collaborations: {user_id: user_id}) }
```

This is the SQL which is output'ed in console:

```
SELECT "collabs".* FROM "collabs" LEFT OUTER JOIN "collaborations" ON "collaborations"."collab_id" = "collabs"."id" WHERE ("collaborations"."user_id" != $1)  [["user_id", 13]]
```

This works if the child associations only has the provided user_id, but it the collab has another collaboration with another user_id, then this collab is fetched with the scopes described above.

Comment: Is this MySQL, postgresql, ...?

Comment: @codenamev I’m using postgres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your call:

```
Collab.find_by_sql [
  "SELECT *
  FROM collabs
  WHERE id NOT IN (
      SELECT C.id
      FROM collabs C
      JOIN collaborations CL ON CL.collab_id = C.id
      WHERE CL.user_id = :user_id)",
  { user_id: user_id }
]
```

**Explanation:** To fetch collabs which do not have collaborations for selected user_id it's necessary to find those which have that collaborations, and exclude them. :)

Without SQL, with plain Ruby, it could be written as:

```
Collab.where.not(
  id: Collab.joins(:collaborations)
            .where(collaborations: { user_id: user_id })
            .pluck(:id)
)
```

Or, with more details:

```
# Inner query to find collabs with collaborations for given user_id:
#   SELECT C.id
#   FROM collabs C
#     JOIN collaborations CL ON CL.collab_id = C.id
#   WHERE CL.user_id = :user_id
ids = Collab.joins(:collaborations)
            .where(collaborations: { user_id: user_id })
            .pluck(:id)

# Final query:
#   SELECT *
#   FROM collabs
#   WHERE id NOT IN :ids
Collab.where.not(id: ids)
```

It produces two SQL calls instead of one in 1st case (find_by_sql), so for performance sake please avoid doing so.

Comment: Okay, but why is the last one making two calls, when first is making one?

Comment: 1st call - to find ids of collabs that have collaborations for given user_id. 2nd call - to exclude them.

Comment: It works great, thanks. I would also like to know how to make same call in plain ruby, without making two calls, if there is even way to do that

Comment: Yes, that makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use `where.not` instead of `where`

```
scope :available_for_user, -> (user_id) { joins(:collaborations).where.not(collaborations: {user_id: user_id}) }
```

Comment: Sorry, that was what I had, just mistyped in the question. Edited it

Answer (score 0):

Another option is grouping the `Collaborations`s by `collab_id`, then use an aggregate function to map all user ids for each Collab and checking against it:

```
scope :available_for_user, -> (user_id) {
  joins(<<~CUSTOM_SQL_JOIN
    INNER JOIN (
      SELECT collab_id, array_agg(user_id) as user_ids FROM collaborations GROUP BY collab_id
    ) collaborations_by_collab ON #{user_id} IN collaborations_by_collab.user_ids
  CUSTOM_SQL_JOIN
  )
}
```

Ref: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-aggregate.html